# error al iniciar ionic /// @ionic/app-scripts : not installed

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework

`@ionic/app-scripts : not installed`

I am using a mac I need to run an application in ionic realize the installation of node js and the one of ionic but when using ionic serve it always indicates to me that it is not installed ionic serve

`@ ionic / app-scripts: not installed`

I get this from the user `ionic.info`

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You could reinstall ionic like below:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g ionic@3.20.1
```

after that, create new project like:

```
ionic start myApp blank
```